# Chessboard pattern (spaces and zeroes) not working with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is just a simple little exercise, but something doesn't seem to be working and I'm not quite sure why. What I'm trying to do is make a chess board pattern out of 0's and spaces, such that there are no spaces or 0's directly next to, above or below a different space or 0. For some reason, they seem to line up in columns of 0s and spaces like so:

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

rather than alternating. Here is my Javascript:

```
var length = 8;
var board = "";

$(document).ready(function() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                $('#chessboard').append(" ");
            } else {
                $('#chessboard').append("0");
            };
        };
        $('#chessboard').append("<br/>");
    };
});
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This works as intended, but the spaces are invisible. Use a dash (-) instead of a space and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

It is alternating! You just need a bigger space than a whitespace to reflect the same changes that height is making.

Instead of `$('#chessboard').append(" ");`, You can make that a larger whitespace such as

```
`$('#chessboard').append("&emsp;");`
```

Comment: You forgot the semicolon after `&emsp`

Answer (score 1):

It works as intended, but the spaces are getting omitted when viewing it. As you can see with the example below, which uses a dash instead of a space, it works.

```js
var length = 8;
var board = "";

$(document).ready(function() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                $('#chessboard').append("-");
            } else {
                $('#chessboard').append("0");
            };
        };
        $('#chessboard').append("<br/>");
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chessboard"></div>
```